# How to combine these sentences

Tags: conjunctions, relative-pronouns, sentence-combination

> 1) The panel on the left side specifies the values of the context variables.
>
> 2) It shows that the current section must be "full-text" and the current title (the last seen heading) must be "References".

However, now I think they would be better to be separated but just for the sake of learning, how could I combine them?

Could I say

- 1) The panel on the left side specifies the values of the context variables, **showing that** the current section must be "full-text" and the current title (the last seen heading) must be "References".
- 2) The panel on the left side specifies the values of the context variables, **in which** the current section must be "full-text" and the current title (the last seen heading) must be "References".
- 3) The panel on the left side specifies the values of the context variables, **so** the current section must be "full-text" and the current title (the last seen heading) must be "References".

Answer (score 2):

Item (2) appears to be okay, but I will combine the sentences using "wherein", upon considering that:

1) 'in which' and 'wherein' are synonyms (source below), but the latter sounds more formal (I usually encounter in legal documents)

> wherein
>   wɛːrˈɪn/
>   formal
>   adverb
>   1.
>   in which.
>   "the situation wherein the information will eventually be used"
>   2.
>   in what place or respect?
>   "so wherein lies the difference?"

https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=wherein&oq=wherein&aqs=chrome.0.57j60l3j59l2.960&sugexp=chrome,mod=5&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: An upvote with a note: would be nice to see the question's sentence with "wherein" in place